# English translation of german bureaucratic term: "Weglegesache"

Tags: translation, german

The German bureaucratic term *Weglegesache* is used in German public administration to refer to documents that they are forced to keep for a certain amount of time, but which are very unlikely ever to get retrieved/used.

I am searching for a translation that keeps the bureaucratic context and communicates that it refers to a bureaucratic action. The term *Weglegesache* is intended to be used as a title for a piece of art, so I can't just describe it in the translation.

Comment: The literal translation would appear to be "laid-away thing" or slightly more idiomatically, "laid-up thing". When I was working in the Civil Service we used to have files **put away** but that's almost jargon because it *could* (but doesn't) just mean "stored in the cupboard". "Put away" meant "sent to the bowels of the Repository for the next hundred years".

Comment: You could do a search on "_Filed under pending_" to see if that bureaucratic term meets your needs.

Comment: but doesn't "Filed under pending" just mean it hasn't been resolved yet?

Comment: Does just plain 'archived' sound right?

Comment: @Mitch That's what we used to call such documents in British local government.

Comment: @Leander. In my civil service office many years ago, _filed under pending_ was our euphemism for filing a letter in the hope that there would be no follow-up. The expression seems to be used in this way in some of the Google books links in the first page of my Google search on the term:https://www.google.com/search?q=%22filed+under+pending%22&ei=gzMFXYKgAsjDwQLDn7KoCg&start=0&sa=N&ved=0ahUKEwjC7YjqieziAhXIYVAKHcOPDKU4KBDy0wMIaA&biw=1522&bih=706

Comment: *Inactive files* or *archived files* perhaps.  Or *File this in the Morgue."

Comment: @Shoe I will research a bit about "filed under pending", but it seems like the best translation. If you submit it as an answer i can accept it! Thanks for the effort!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bureaucratic term "*file/d under pending*" can mean neutrally "*file/d until it comes up for a scheduled action or until some event makes it current again*".

But it can also have the connotation "*file/d in the hope or expectation that no further action will ever be taken on it*".

For example,

> "Everything can be filed under pending."

From a humorous collection of "*[incredibly useful terms for the workplace](https://iamtravelr.com/threads/5273/)*".

And the following extracts from three Google books which show up on the first page of a search on "*filed under pending*" also appear to have the same connotation of "*filed and (intentionally) forgotten*":

[image]

Source: [Legal and other Issues in Repatriating Nigeria's Looted Artefacts](https://books.google.de/books?id=4ZrxAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA95&lpg=PA95&dq=%22filed%20under%20pending%22&source=bl&ots=1ZFPmTsOrq&sig=ACfU3U3NGucESXYZzvqpDdtFLzCJnADjNg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiXzKCqw_ziAhWVolwKHX6HCnUQ6AEwBXoECAUQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22filed%20under%20pending%22&f=false)

[image]

Source: [Making an Exhibition of Myself: the autobiography of Peter Hall](https://books.google.de/books?id=M4Ic5qxGjwUC&pg=PT426&lpg=PT426&dq=%22filed%20under%20pending%22&source=bl&ots=eKCwex24eO&sig=ACfU3U17waQQ7rlZPUH_AkLGBtIdNHV2Pw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiXzKCqw_ziAhWVolwKHX6HCnUQ6AEwBnoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22filed%20under%20pending%22&f=false)

[image]

Source: [Why we die](https://books.google.de/books?id=O8ytBwAAQBAJ&pg=PT105&lpg=PT105&dq=%22filed%20under%20pending%22&source=bl&ots=Yc-6MzolGv&sig=ACfU3U2C4WiG7AJNQc42U04vGKNta_x74g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiXzKCqw_ziAhWVolwKHX6HCnUQ6AEwCXoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22filed%20under%20pending%22&f=false)

In my opinion *Filed under pending* would be a good, ambiguous title for a work of art.

Answer (score 0):

I won't say it's in common usage (I came across it in a book by Leslie Thomas) but **Moribund Documents** would be a good phrase here.